# Shared Access Signatures (SAS)

Tags: azure, token, azure-storage, azure-sas

I'm using Shared Access Signatures (SAS) But when it comes to "Allowed IP addresses", when I give one IP address i can not access the SA with that SAS.
I have tried without IP address it works

Comment: what is SA here ?

Comment: What's the IP address you're giving? SAS URL will only work when you access it from the IP address specified in the SAS URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you could access sas with Allowed IP addresses, the most possible reason is you set the wrong ip address.

You should set the `sip` field in your sas token. You could refer to this doc: [Specify an IP address or IP range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#specify-an-ip-address-or-ip-range). You could set a specific id or a range ip.

In my test when the ip is wrong, it will send `AuthorizationFailure` code. So before generate sas query the ip address firstly.